# How do I manage a rapidly growing postgres table in Django?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, bigdata

I have a website that is used to show live data from different machines in a crushing facility. Right now the "Sensor Data" obtained from all the machines in one facility is stored in a "sensordata" table and this data is used by the user to make reports for a time period(upto last three months). The site has been running for 3 months now and the sensor data table is already at 113 million rows. My company is planning to add even more facilities( this will multiply the number of machines). What's a good solution to store this large an amount of data from on which analysis is to be performed in the future(even create reports and such)?(That's also future safe for say 100's of facilities)

Comment: have you considered `table partitioning`?

Comment: @JimJones That was my initial thought as well. But I wanted to know if that was the common solution django developers use to these problems and how effective it really is as the tables grow much bigger

Comment: Alright. I just believe the database layer is the proper place to address such an issue - it is imho the more sustainable approach. Good luck!

Comment: `table partitioning` with compression maybe to keep the data size smaller on disk.. One disadvantage would be more CPU cycles are needed to compress and decompress the data.. But CPU's nowadays are so fast and powerfull i geuss you would not really notice the extra overhead that's needed to compress and decompress the data